# Flatten an array for D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, d3.js

I am importing data from mongoDB, I am using javascript and React. I need to flatten the array for D3.js.

I have:

```
[{
        "location": [ { "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z" } ],
        "count": 2,
        "item": [ { "name": "football" } ]
},{
        "location": [ { "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z" } ],
        "count": 1,
        "item": [ { "name": "Baseball" } ]
}]
```

But would like:

```
[{
        "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z",
        "count": 2,
        "name": "football" 
    },{
        "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z" ,
        "count": 1,
        "name": "baseball"
    }]
```

I tried to iterate through the objects but got:

```
{
0.item.0.name:  "baseball"
0.count: 1
0.location.0.createdAt: "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z"
1.etc...
}
```

I also tried:
`console.log(array.flatMap((element) => element).flat()) ;`

But that did not do anything

Comment: is it always 1 elemet in the location and item arrays

Comment: `arr.map((x) => ({createdAt:x.location[0].createdAt,count:x.count,name:x.item[0].name}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and destructuring:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "location": [{ "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z" }],
    "count": 2,
    "item": [{ "name": "football" }]
  },
  {
    "location": [{ "createdAt": "2023-04-03T18:27:42.088Z" }],
    "count": 1,
    "item": [{ "name": "Baseball" }]
  }
];

const flattened = data.map(({ location: [{ createdAt }], count, item: [{ name }] }) => ({
  createdAt,
  count,
  name
}));

console.log(flattened);
```